# System doesn't see my dvd drive as a recorder

Tags: dvd, cd-drive

Ever since upgrading to 14.04 (I believe - I didn't try to burn anything for a while), my system has not been able to burn CD/DVD.
It's seen as "Slimtype DVD A  DS8A8SH (KAA2)" mounted as /dev/sr0 (Read-only).
I didn't have issues before and I don't know why it would be mounting as read only now.